# Making draft page as the main page

Tags: homepage, draft

A very newbie question.

I wanted to update my home page. I copied it as a draft and made the modifications. Now.. how do I make it the main home page? It sounds very simple but have been totally unable to do so. My home page has only my website as the permalink.. I'm unable to change it. My updated homepage has permalink home-5. I'm stuck between the two pages.

I'd also like to backup my original homepage for record purpose.

Can anyone suggest how to do that, step-by-step?

Comment: Have you tried editing the permalink?

Comment: Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-duplicator/ to create a copy of your page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the "Settings" menu
2. Then to "Reading"
3. Click the "A static page" radio button next to "Front Page Displays"
4. And select your "page-5" in the dropdown next to "Front Page". Make
   sure you have a blog page selected as well.

(The image is from the Codex. The correct buttons are not clicked but that is the page your are looking for.)

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks.. that solved my problem as far as the Front Page is concerned. However, my question remains. If I copy any page as a draft, make changes, save it, publish it, and want it to replace the old page, how do I do that?

Comment: You don't. You can't "swap" pages via any mechanism in Core that I know of. Pages aren't built that way. I don't see anything in the question about swapping pages in general, only about swapping the home page.

Comment: Rinse, repeat. He showed you how to change the home page so that's how you change the home page - every time you make a new page/version you'll need to follow those steps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the accepted method or not but, for me, it was easy to remove the "old" page from the menu (under Appearance -> Menus) and add the new one.  You have to Publish the new page before you can add it though.  This applies to everything except the Home page, which I think was the original question.